# How do I restrict my hovering style to only the button and not the entire table row?

Tags: html, css, button, hover, html-table

I’m trying to create a different style for a button when you hover over it as opposed to when it is just sitting there.  So I have created these styles

```
.btn {
    font-family: "Montserrat","HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    font-size: 0.8125em;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    max-width: 100%;
margin: 0;
line-height: 1.42;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: normal;
border: 1px solid transparent;
-moz-user-select: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0;
background-color: #1c1d1d;
color: #fff;
    text-indent: 0rem;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1.42em; /* Same as line-height */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.buttonContainer *:hover {
    margin: 0 0 0px 0;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

This works, except when I hover over my button, the entire table row changes color — https://jsfiddle.net/eyettch5/ .  Here is the HTML

```
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
      <span class="buttonContainer"><form class="button_to" method="post" action="/user_race_time_matches/create?id=2194be1c-6831-4c8a-b096-34e25e6284bb" data-remote="true"><input class="btn saveDetails" value="Save" type="submit"><input name="authenticity_token" value="peb/GNeHaRFs+9DGeqbxRh5tK8yuURQLoN1cOZUEMmCvGyv6Nkpo9gPMjidbjCepZ79Kca44aV5Wrd9+i6NaiA==" type="hidden"></form></span>  
    </td></tr>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get only the button in question to change color upon hovering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `:hover` target:

```
.buttonContainer .saveDetails:hover {}
```

The above should work.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2fy02obk/**

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
.buttonContainer *:hover {
  ...
}
```

to

```
.buttonContainer:hover .saveDetails {
   ...
}
```

-> You hover the container, but you want to change the settings of the button inside the container

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xfxpfx8/1/

Answer (score -1):

change `.buttonContainer *:hover{...}` to `.buttonContainer:hover{...}`

and change

`<input class="btn saveDetails" value="Save" type="submit">`

to

`<input class="btn buttonContainer saveDetails" value="Save" type="submit">`

Comment: This is not the right way to do. Button container should be a container not the button itself.